# Add a non realm object as ignored property to realm object in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to add a non-realm class object to realm object something like this.

```
class TrainTripItinerary: Object {
    dynamic var  departStationName: String?
    dynamic var  departStationCode: String?
    var runningStatus: TrainRunningStatus?

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["runningStatus"]
    }

}
```

While TrainRunningStatus is not a realm class.

```
class TrainRunningStatus {
    var trainDataFound: String?
    var startDate: String?
    var startDayDiff: String?
}
```

I am not able to update runningstatus property now. Anyone know how it works? I fetch separately runnningstatus and assign it to the realm object later but it stays nil even after the assignment.

eg.

```
let runningStatus = TrainRunningStatus()
trainTripItinerary.runningStatus = runningStatus
```

This line is not working, trainTripItinerary runningStatus property is not set properly its always nil.

Comment: What do you mean you aren't able to update it? You can't set it to a new value?

Comment: Yeah! Updated my question as well.

Comment: And if you put a breakpoint right after setting it to a new value, it stays nil? That sounds odd and I suspect it is being set to nil somewhere else. Since it's an ignored property, if you fetch the object *after* setting it, it will be nil, since it isn't being saved.

Comment: Please keep in mind that ignored properties won’t automatically update their value if the same property on another instance representing the same Realm object is changed, so make sure that you update the correct instance. And make sure you update this property after you fetch objects, these properties are not persisted.

Comment: @ConnorNeville  yes I don't want to persist it so I just want to keep it while app is running. I assign them by fetching it from the network and want that property during that app session only. But the weird thing is this property is still nil after the assignment.

Comment: In conjunction with Dmitry's comment, definitely check by placing a breakpoint right after you set the var. It's highly likely it is being set, you're just modifying it (or another reference to it) later.

Comment: @ConnorNeville Hi, Updated my question as well. Yeah I did same and its not working.

Comment: Please provide a complete test case. The "eg." is not enough code to give an answer. How are you checking that the property is `nil` (debugging, assertion, logging...)?

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in comments make sure you use the same instance of `TrainTripItinerary` because ignored properties won’t automatically update their value across different instances.

See an example code below that demonstrates how ignored properties work

```
let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write {
    realm.deleteAll()
}

let runningStatus = TrainRunningStatus()

var trainTripItinerary = TrainTripItinerary()
trainTripItinerary.runningStatus = runningStatus

assert(trainTripItinerary.runningStatus != nil)

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(trainTripItinerary);
}

assert(trainTripItinerary.runningStatus != nil)

trainTripItinerary = realm.objects(TrainTripItinerary.self).first!

assert(trainTripItinerary.runningStatus == nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your code is not correct.

```
class TrainTripItinerary: Object {
    dynamic var  departStationName: String?
    dynamic var  departStationCode: String?
    var runningStatus: TrainRunningStatus?

    override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["runningStatus"]
    }
}
```

`func ignoredProperties() -> [String]` is only used on Realm properties. Since your property `var runningStatus: TrainRunningStatus?` does not begin with `dynamic`, it is not a Realm property. You don't need to use `func ignoredProperties() -> [String]` here.

`var runningStatus: TrainRunningStatus?` here is called a "transient property" in Realm. Usually a transient property is something calculated basing on current date or on Realm properties, Realm won't do anything on transient properties and you should maintain them yourself.

So if you just want to use `runningStatus` as a transient property, you can simply remove the code `override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String]`.